MS Teams Meeting App - gulp ngrok-serve error
I get the error below when I run gulp bgrok-serve
>>gulp ngrok-serve --debug  
[16:34:54] Found additional Yo Teams plugin: yoteams-deploy
[16:34:54] Using gulpfile ~\OneDrive - HEGELMAT\Desktop\Projects\LEARN-MSTEAMS-MEETINGS\gulpfile.js
[16:34:54] Starting 'ngrok-serve'...
[16:34:54] Starting 'start-ngrok'...
[16:34:54] [NGROK] starting ngrok...
[16:34:54] 'start-ngrok' errored after 90 ms
[16:34:54] Error: kill EPERM
    at ChildProcess.kill (node:internal/child_process:511:26)
    at setAuthtoken (C:\Users\hegel\OneDrive - XXXXX\Desktop\Projects\LEARN-MSTEAMS-MEETINGS\node_modules\ngrok\src\process.js:149:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async Object.connect (C:\Users\hegel\OneDrive - XXXXX\Desktop\Projects\LEARN-MSTEAMS-MEETINGS\node_modules\ngrok\index.js:18:5)
[16:34:54] Finished 'ngrok-serve' after 99 ms

**I am able to manually start ngrok using this **
>> ngrok http 3007 --url xxxxx.ngrok.app 

enter image description here
I think the issue is with the gulp task but I do not know how to go about it.
This is my ngrokTasks.js (default).
"use strict";
// Copyright (c) Wictor Wilén. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.ngrokTasks = void 0;
const fancy_log_1 = __importDefault(require("fancy-log"));
const ngrok_1 = __importDefault(require("ngrok"));
const _1 = require(".");
const plugin_error_1 = __importDefault(require("plugin-error"));
const ngrokTasks = (gulp, config) => {
    gulp.task("start-ngrok", (cb) => {
        (0, fancy_log_1.default)("[NGROK] starting ngrok...");
        const conf = {
            subdomain: process.env.NGROK_SUBDOMAIN,
            region: process.env.NGROK_REGION,
            addr: process.env.PORT,
            authtoken: process.env.NGROK_AUTH
        };
        ngrok_1.default.connect(conf).then((url) => {
            (0, fancy_log_1.default)("[NGROK] Url: " + url);
            if (!conf.authtoken) {
                (0, fancy_log_1.default)("[NGROK] You have been assigned a random ngrok URL that will only be available for this session. You will need to re-upload the Teams manifest next time you run this command.");
            }
            let hostName = url.replace("http://", "");
            hostName = hostName.replace("https://", "");
            (0, fancy_log_1.default)("[NGROK] PUBLIC_HOSTNAME set to: " + hostName);
            process.env.PUBLIC_HOSTNAME = hostName;
            (0, fancy_log_1.default)("[NGROK] Inspect Url: " + ngrok_1.default.getUrl());
            cb();
        }).catch((err) => {
            cb(new plugin_error_1.default("yoteams-build.core", err));
        });
    });
    gulp.task("ngrok-serve", (0, _1.dependencies)(gulp, "ngrok-serve", "start-ngrok", "manifest", "serve"));
};
exports.ngrokTasks = ngrokTasks;

I am running out of idea on what to try. Please help.
